# How do I run a command after launching the debugger in the C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have an embedded C project which I run on an ARM Cortex M4 on a custom board or a devkit, using gcc on a Mac. I've been using Visual Studio Code as an IDE for embedded C work for a bit and am now looking to use the debugger in it to control gdb.

There are three processes I need to run when debugging:

1. gdb server
2. gdb client
3. A Segger RTT executable, which knows where to look in the target memory for my logging and displays it on the terminal.

I now have a launch.json file setup that can handle #1 and #2 OK, but I still need to set up #3.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gdb launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/pca10040/_build/app.out",
            "logging": {
                "exceptions": true,
                "moduleLoad": true,
                "programOutput": true,
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true,
                "traceResponse": true
            },
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/app/pca10040",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "debugServerPath": "/Applications/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer",
                "debugServerArgs": "-device nRF52832_xxAA -if swd -speed 4000",
                "serverStarted": "Connected to target",
                "miDebuggerPath": "${env:HOME}/dev/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb",
                "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:2331",
                "args": [
                    "-x ${workspaceRoot}/app/pca10040/_build/.gdbinit"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The executable for #3 has to be run *after* #2 is running. It takes no arguments. I'd like its output to show up in one of the panes down the bottom ("output" or "debug console", doesn't matter).

The docs (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md) mention a `launchCompleteCommand`, but that's not what I need - that goes to gdb.

I guess I could create a task for this, but that's another thing to run manually after I hit "debug" and I want this to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your debugger is already working and you added Segger libraries to your project, you have to add this to your configuration of `launch.json`:

```
            "rttConfig": {
            "enabled": true,
            "address": "auto",
            "decoders": [
                {
                    "label": "",
                    "port": 0,
                    "type": "console"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Then you should be able to get RTT output in Terminal pane of VS Code.